# Combine content of two different queries - shell/bash/arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, docker, awk

I stuck on the following problem...

I have a shell script that is supposed to create docker networks that do not yet exist from a variable file. The challenge is to create the missing network with this associated subnet,  which is also grepped from the same file.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create tempfiles
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
TMPFILE2=$(mktemp)
TMPFILE3=$(mktemp)

# search for networks in .env file with VARIABLE_NAME
< .env grep '_NET=' | grep -v '#' | sort | cut -d "=" -f2 > "${TMPFILE}" 2>&1

# search for subnetworks in .env file with VARIABLE_NAME
< .env grep '_NET_SUBNET=' | grep -v '#' | sort | sed 's/[^0-9]*//' > "${TMPFILE2}" 2>&1

# Merge
paste -d ' ' ${TMPFILE2} ${TMPFILE} >> ${TMPFILE3}

mapfile -t lines_array < "${TMPFILE3}"

for line in "${lines_array[@]}"; do
    #echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}'
    docker network ls | grep "$line"
    if [ "$(docker network ls | grep -c "$line" | awk '{print $2}' )" == 0 ]
    then
        echo "network $line not exist"
        echo "docker network create -d bridge --subnet=$line"
    else echo "network $line exists"
    fi

done
```

variables from `.env` file:

```
# Network
## traefik proxy network
TF_PROXY_NET=traefik_proxy_net
## subnet network traefik extern
TF_PROXY_NET_SUBNET=172.30.0.0/16
## crowdsex network
CS_NET=crowdsec_net
## subnet network crowdsec
CS_NET_SUBNET=172.31.0.0/16
## docker-socket-proxy network
DSP_NET=dsp_net
##  subnet network docker-socket-proxy
DSP_NET_SUBNET=172.32.0.0/16
```

The idea are:

- grep the complete variable from the network, sort it and put it in a temp file (TMPFILE)
- grep the complete subnetwork variable from file, sort it and put it in a temp file (TMPFILE2)
  = the merge the output from (TMPFILE2) with (TMPFILE) and put it in a file (TMPFILE3)

output TMPFILE3:

```
172.31.0.0/16 crowdsec_net
172.32.0.0/16 dsp_net
172.30.0.0/16 traefik_proxy_net
```

up to this point (maybe a little bit complicated) it's ok...

output "Docker network ls":

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                DRIVER    SCOPE
befbc543b385   bridge              bridge    local
34604e449c61   host                host      local
489eb654d1de   none                null      local
b0520be90b41   traefik_proxy_net   bridge    local
1709315fb264   wikijs_default      bridge    local
```

What I want but doesn't work in the array is the second field from the variable "line"
example: `line = 172.31.0.0/16 crowdsec_net`
second field: `crowdsec_net`

that works:

```
echo $line" | awk '{print $2}'
traefik_proxy_net
crowdsec_net
dsp_net
```

that doesn't work:

```
if [ "$(docker network ls | grep -c "$line" | awk '{print $2}' )" == 0 ]
```

because the $line variable doesnt pay attention for the awk command. means that the complete string will used and the docker network cant be found.

Can anyone help me or suggest me a better alternate for this case?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I've found a solution for now :)

that works:

```
mapfile -t lines_array < "${TMPFILE3}"

for line in "${lines_array[@]}"; do

    docker network ls | grep "$line"
    if [ "$(docker network ls --format "{{.Name}}" | while read i; do echo $i $(docker network inspect $i | grep Subnet | tr -d '"' | sed -e 's/\<Subnet\>//g ' | tr -d ":" ); done | grep "$line" | wc -l )" == 0 ]
    then
        echo "network $line not exist"
        echo "docker network create -d bridge --subnet=$line"
    else echo "network $line exists"
    fi
```

the command searching for docker networks and the associates subnet with the same string/output as in the TMPFILE5

output:

```
network crowdsec_net 172.31.0.0/16 not exist
docker network create -d bridge --subnet=crowdsec_net 172.31.0.0/16
network dsp_net 172.32.0.0/16 not exist
docker network create -d bridge --subnet=dsp_net 172.32.0.0/16
network traefik_proxy_net 172.30.0.0/16 exists
```

**EDIT 2**

Thanks @Gilles Quénot & @markp-fuso

finally, this is the working script (look at the post from @markp-fuso):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r status line
do
    printf "\n########## %s : %s\n" "${status}" "${line}"

    if [[ "${status}" = 'create' ]]
    then
        echo "network '${line} not exist"
        echo "docker network create -d bridge --subnet=${line}"
    else
        echo "network ${line} exists"
    fi
done < <( awk -f env.awk <(docker network ls) .env )
```

great work, thanks @all :)

Comment: good point. follows immediately

Comment: you're right! These were among the first attempts when I tried to combine two arrays...that was too complicated for me. Edited it.

Comment: Do you have access to a higher-level language, like Python, maybe with a native Docker SDK?  The code you write there might be more readable and maintainable than the string-manipulation in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you bring `awk` into the mix there's a good chance you can eliminate calls to `grep`, `cut` and `sed`, not to mention reduce the number of times `.env` has to be parsed. In this case a single `awk` script also allows us to improve overall performance by eliminating a lot of subshell invocations.

To simulate OP's `docker network ls` call:

```
$ cat docker.out
NETWORK ID     NAME                DRIVER    SCOPE
befbc543b385   bridge              bridge    local
34604e449c61   host                host      local
489eb654d1de   none                null      local
b0520be90b41   traefik_proxy_net   bridge    local
1709315fb264   wikijs_default      bridge    local
```

One `awk` idea that replaces most of OP's current code:

```
$ cat parse_env.awk
FNR==NR        { if (FNR>1)                          # 1st file: "docker network ls" output; skip header then ...
                    net[$2]                          # save 2nd field (NAME) as index in net[] array
                 next
               }
FNR==1         { FS = "="                            # 2nd file: redefine input field separator
                 $0 = $0                             # force reparsing of current/first row with new FS; overkill if first row is guaranteed to be of no interest
               }
/#/            { next     }                          # skip lines with comments
               { id = $1    }                        # first "=" delimited field; bogus assignment for rows we are not interested in 
/_NET=/        { sub(/_NET/,"",id)                   # line contains "_NET="? strip "_NET" to get id then ...
                 names[id] = $2                      # save name
               }
/_NET_SUBNET=/ { sub(/_NET_SUBNET/,"",id)            # same as for "_NET="; strip "_NET_SUBNET" to get id then ...
                 ips[id] = $2                        # save ip
               }
END            { for (id in names)                   # loop through array indices
                    
                      # if names[i] is an index in the net[] array then prepend "exists" else "create"
                      print (names[id] in net ? "exists" : "create"), ips[id], names[id]
               }
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ awk -f parse_env.awk <(cat docker.out) .env
exists 172.30.0.0/16 traefik_proxy_net
create 172.31.0.0/16 crowdsec_net
create 172.32.0.0/16 dsp_net
```

**NOTES:**

- OP would replace `<(cat docker.out)` with `<(docker network ls)`
- if OP needs the data sorted in a particular order the output can be piped to `sort` as needed

Replacing OP's `for` loop with a comparable `while` loop, and feeding the `while` loop from the `awk` output, gives us the final set of code:

```
while read -r status line
do
    printf "\n########## %s : %s\n" "${status}" "${line}"

    if [[ "${status}" = 'create' ]]
    then
        echo "network '${line} not exist"
        echo "docker network create -d bridge --subnet=${line}"
    else
        echo "network ${line} exists"
    fi
done < <( awk -f parse_env.awk <(cat docker.out) .env )
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
########## exists : 172.30.0.0/16 traefik_proxy_net
network 172.30.0.0/16 traefik_proxy_net exists

########## create : 172.31.0.0/16 crowdsec_net
network '172.31.0.0/16 crowdsec_net not exist
docker network create -d bridge --subnet=172.31.0.0/16 crowdsec_net

########## create : 172.32.0.0/16 dsp_net
network '172.32.0.0/16 dsp_net not exist
docker network create -d bridge --subnet=172.32.0.0/16 dsp_net
```

Comment: oh, thank you for taking your time. I will give them a try. Thanks

Comment: wow, you are a magician. really, it works...and it seems so simple :) Perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
if [ "$(docker network ls | grep -c "$line" | awk '{print $2}' )" == 0 ]
```

you could do with bash's arithmetic operator:

```
count=$(docker network ls | awk -v line=$line '$2 ~ line{c++}END{print c}')
if ((count == 0)); then
    echo "0"
else
    echo "> 0"
fi
```

---

`((...))` and `$((...))` are arithmetic commands, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. It's a good point but it doesn't solve my problem. For your advice, the count should only be for the second field in the $line variable, because the second field is the docker network I want to grep

Comment: I edited my post for a better understanding.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Output is continious "0". Look at my editted post. One Network exist. Output should be 0, 0, >0. I've also tried with my new search string and get an error `./mapfile_tests.sh: line 53: ((: traefik_proxy_net 172.30.0.0/16: syntax error in expression (error token is "172.30.0.0/16")`

Comment: It will cost you the whole day :) 
doesn't work anymore. output: `awk: cmd. line:1: if $2 ~ line{c++}END{print c}
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
0`

Comment: i forgot to enable the array...but still no success
`awk: fatal: cannot open file `if $2 ~ line{c++}END{print c}' for reading: No such file or directory
0
awk: fatal: cannot open file `if $2 ~ line{c++}END{print c}' for reading: No such file or directory
0
awk: fatal: cannot open file `if $2 ~ line{c++}END{print c}' for reading: No such file or directory
0`

Comment: nearly the same result as in my last post:
`awk: fatal: cannot open file `$2 ~ line{c++}END{print c}' for reading: No such file or directory
0
awk: fatal: cannot open file `$2 ~ line{c++}END{print c}' for reading: No such file or directory
0
awk: fatal: cannot open file `$2 ~ line{c++}END{print c}' for reading: No such file or directory
0

Comment: `${line}` contains a space so `-v line=$line` should be `-v line="$line"` to eliminate an  `awk` error